# How to build lucene indexes on CD server

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7

I have two servers one for Content Management website and one Content Delivery website. Both server have below configuration.

CM Server:
1) IIS on which website running.
2) Sitecore folders and files.
3) Core, Master and web database
4) Website code files/folders.

CD server
1) IIS on which website running.
2) There is no Sitecore folders and files.
3) Core and common web database.
4) Website code files/folders.

Note: Web database is common among both the websites.

I can browse website pages from both the sites
but Sitecore from CM website only as CD site does not have sitecore files.

My some of the pages are picking up content from Lucene Indexes.

Now I build lucene indexing from Sitecore (CM website) from Control panel, the indexes were successfully built inside the data folder of CM server and no Indexes were created inside Data folder of CD website.

I tried copying the indexes first time on CD server but when I publish the changes, it only updated the indexes on CM server data folder and not on CD server data folder.

I would like to create the indexing inside Data folder on the CM as well as on the CD server when item is being published.

Configuration of Index is

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Publish strategy is "onPublishEndAsync"
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your cd server has another database then you should change this part the config for that server to:

```
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
  <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <Database>NAMEOF-CD1-DATABASE</Database>
    <Root>/sitecore</Root>
  </crawler>
</locations>
```

Edit: I see you have 'web' database across servers, so above does not apply to your situation.

Also check if you have Scalability settings enabled (stated in 4.1 of Scaling Guide). If this is not enabled then events fired on CM server will not fire on (remote) CD server.
  http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Scaling%20Guide.aspx

Edit again: I found this article explaining the different update strategies. You should take a look at the RemoteRebuildStrategy. This strategy allows CD servers to listen to the rebuild events.
  http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Index-Update-Strategies.aspx